# ios Viewのサイズについて

Tags: xcode, ios8

ViewのWidthやHeightとはどのような単位となるのでしょうか？
ドットなのでしょうか

Comment: 私はいつもピクセルで計算して開発しています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

単位は「ポイント」です。
　iOSデバイスの場合、Retinaディスプレイでない端末では1ポイント=1ピクセル、Retinaディスプレイ端末(iPhone6(s)Plusを除く)では1ポイント=2ピクセルになります。

余談ですが、DTPの世界では72ポイント=1インチですが、ディスプレイ上ではそのディスプレイの解像度に依存します。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ポイントなのですか。解像度ともあいまって勉強が必要そうです。
もう少し調べてみます。